# How do I get a list of users who LIKED a post to show in admin of page?

Tags: facebook

I know there are tools like Social Metrix and such. But I want to not just see a list of how many LIKES but a list of my wordpress users who liked it so I can email just them about the article.

Answer (score 1):

Short of polling the likes of every facebook user, you don't. That information isn't public.

Answer (score 0):

Otto's answer doesn't appear to be entirely true...  you CAN see at least some of the people who liked it...

I'm not going to try to edit someone else's great answer and make it worse... your possible solution is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992193/who-likes-my-post-on-facebook-social-plugin..

Another possible solution would be to have a spot for users to put their email before clicking the like button...